# Are Kotlin channels used in coroutines thread safe / synchronized / keep happens-before relationship?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

Are the functions available in Kotlin channels thread safe? e.g.

```
val channel = Channel<Boolean>()
val job1 = GlobalScope.launch {
    channel.send(true)
}
val job2 = GlobalScope.launch {
    val x = channel.poll()
}
```

If in the above code `job1` was executed by the machine (in real time) before `job2` is executed and on different threads, is it guaranteed that `x` is set with `true`? Or is it possible that it gets set with `null` (because cpu cache was not updated)?

Answer (score 1):

`Channel` class kotlinx.coroutines library is thread-safe. It is designed to support multiple threads.

`GlobalScope.launch` may not necessarily mean a coroutine will be executed in a new thread

Answer (score 0):

> If in the above code `job1` was executed by the machine (in real time) before `job2` is executed and on different threads, is it guaranteed that `x` is set with `true`? Or is it possible that it gets set with `null` (because cpu cache was not updated)?

The Java Memory Model has no notion of time and it doesn't guarantee anything just based on the fact that a line executed earlier than another one. You can't even ascertain when an action was executed on a CPU.

In the code you posted, there are two concurrently executing coroutines. *If and only if* `channel.poll()` gets a non-null value, there is a *happens-before* edge going from `send()` to `poll()`. If it gets a null-value, there is no *happens-before* edge.

Let's say you determine the wall-clock time in the two coroutines, something like the following:

```
var sendTime: Long = 0
var receiveTime: Long = 0

suspend fun main() {
    val channel = Channel<Boolean>(UNLIMITED)
    val job1 = GlobalScope.launch {
        channel.send(true)
        sendTime = System.nanoTime()
    }
    val job2 = GlobalScope.launch {
        receiveTime = System.nanoTime()
        val x = channel.poll()
        println(x)
    }
    job1.join()
    job2.join()
    println("${receiveTime - sendTime}")
}
```

The fact that `receiveTime` is greater than `sendTime` does not induce a *happens-before* relationship and it doesn't force `channel.poll()` to observe the sent item. Calling `nanoTime()` is not a synchronization action.

Note that these facts have nothing to do Kotlin or coroutines specifically, this is how the Java Memory Model works. If you study the C++ memory model, you'll find it works the same way.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. The code sample I provided just shows the 2 functions I'm interested in. In my code there's other logic in which what matters is a specific scenario. If the line of code `channel.send(true)` was executed before the line `val x = channel.poll()` then I need to get `x == true` (not null). If `poll()` was executed before `send(true)` then I don't care.
If instead of a Channel I'll use Java's BlockingQueue then I'll get the above behaviour (due to synchronization).
Is `Channel.poll()` synchronized with `Channel.send()`?

Comment: If you are interested in the formal guarantees provided by the JVM, then the time ordering between `send` and `poll` has no relevance. This applies to the `BlockingQueue` as well. But I wonder what exactly you mean by "executed earlier", how do you know when something executed?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html
Actually, I think it will have minimal impact on the code behavior (only wait time in a loop will be affected).